# Layout XML block rendered twice in Magento skin

Tags: layout, blocks, local.xml

I'm having a bit of trouble with a custom layout block which I'm trying to add to the *head.phtml* file of my theme. Basically, I'm trying to add extra favicon definitions to the header of my document.

In my local.xml file, I've added the lines:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/template" name="favicon.extra" as="favicon.extra" template="page/html/head/favicon-extra.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

And then inside *head.phtml*, I'm calling this as a *childHtml* template as:

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('favicon.extra') ?>
```

The problem is that the block is rendered twice, in two different spots:

1. Underneath the other favicons, as per the *head.phtml* getChildHtml call, and
2. After the other scripts in the header

The desired outcome is that I **only want the first of these two to render**.

From what I've read, I think this has to do with that particular block/reference being automatically rendered via the toHtml output - is this correct?

If so, is there a better/correct way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here? Is there another way to **remove the second render**?

Any help possible is much appreciated.

*Note: apologies if this is considered bad practice but I'm reposting a question I posted on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348878/layout-xml-block-rendered-twice-in-magento-skin) as I thought this might be a more appropriate forum.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the line

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('favicon.extra') ?>
```

in `head.phtml`.
There is already this line that renders all child blocks

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

**[EDIT]**
If for some reason you want to add the block in a specific place, you can use this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('favicon.extra') ?>
<?php this->unsetChild('favicon.extra');?>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I want the block rendered in the position defined by the position of my output line in head.phtml. Removing this line _does_ remove the duplicate block output, but it also means the block isn't rendered in the right location.

Comment: @fvzzy I don't know why would you want that. It's the `<head>` tag. But I'm sure you have a reason. You can try reverting to your original code and after the line that renders your block add this `$this->unsetChild('favicon.extra')`

Comment: Seems a bit counterintuitive but whatever - totally worked. Champion. Thanks!

Comment: @fvzzy. Glad it works. I added it to the answer also.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to remove the xml code from  `local.xml`  and instead of

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('favicon.extra') ?>
```

in the `header.phtml` , use following code:

```
<?php  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('page/html/head/favicon-extra.phtml'); ?>
```

Comment: Seems like an elegant solution but didn't have any luck getting this to work unfortunately. Doesn't seem to render anything in that spot at all.

Comment: are you still struggling, Marius answer seems a better solution.