# Call custom block on Success Page Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I need to call a custom block on success page

I have tried by layout as mention below

```
   <checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml" >
                <block type="core/template" name="birthday" template="checkout/message/birthday.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
```

In success page

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('birthday');
```

I am getting birthday block twice on the page.

Please let me know how we can call custom block on success page.

I don't want to use dynamic block i.e.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
->setTemplate('checkout/message/birthday.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added an answer for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25722755/2047249).
Here it is again:

You are getting the `birthday` block twice because of this line from success.phtml:

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

This line renders all child blocks of the main block.
If you want it listed only once remove the line

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('birthday');
```

It will be redered by the `getChildHtml` method anyway.

Comment: can we remove echo $this->getChildHtml()

Comment: In theory you can, but if there are other modules that add something to the success page you may lose functionality. If you want your block in a specific location, take a look at this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/32695/146. It's for the header section but it applies to this case also.

Comment: can i use like this echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.success')

Comment: You are already using it like that. the difference is the parameter name.

Comment: because by writing this my issue is resovled

Comment: Are you sure that solves your issue? or that line just prints nothing and you get your block from the `getChildHtml()` method? If you are sure it solves it, post an answer with what you did  and mark it as accepted.

Comment: yes i am sure i am getting proper output.

Answer (score 2):

U have manage this code in checkout.xml

```
   <checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml" >
                <block type="core/template" name="birthday" template="checkout/message/birthday.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>
```

Describe in checkout.xml auto call your bithday.phtml file on success page.

So not use this function on success file.

> echo $this->getChildHtml('birthday');

I have test your code on my site.

When u describe function on file so twice call a file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes i got an anwser.

```
 <checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml" />
    </reference>

    <reference name="checkout.success">
            <block type="core/template" name="birthday" as="birthday" template="checkout/message/birthday.phtml" />
            <block type="core/template" name="test" as="test" template="checkout/message/test.phtml" />
             <block type="core/template" name="test1" template="checkout/message/test1.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

In success page

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('birthday');
echo $this->getChildHtml('test');
echo $this->getChildHtml('test1');
```

Hope this will help others.

Comment: As I suspected. this solution might work for you now, but in case you get later other extensions that add something to the success page you won't get those blocks printed out. What if there is an extension like yours that adds a block called `some_block`.  You will never see that unless you add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('some_block') ?>` to the phtml file

Comment: but i thought this is the only solution for calling custom blocks

Comment: Not quite, as mentioned above `$this->getChildHtml()` will print out your module anyway as it captures _all_ child blocks and renders them. Apologies for bumping this old thread but it's still quite relevant.